# pyqtdeploy creates weird main.pro qmake template

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt, pyqtdeploy

I'm trying to deploy a PyQt4 application with pyqtdeploy.
I can build the pyqtdeploy project, which generates qt source files and a main.pro qmake template file. 
I can run qmake

```
/usr/lib64/qt4/bin/qmake /home/andrea/build/main.pro -r -spec linux-g++ -Wall
```

and it works fine, but when I run make it complains:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtCore_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtSql_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtNetwork_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtGui_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main.pro contains a line with

```
LIBS += [...] -lQtCore_s -lQtSql_s -lQt_s -lQtNetwork_s -lQtGui_s
```

These linker flags are present in the resulting Makefile as well,
I cannot find any of these in the system, I can find these without the trailing _s indeed (i.e. libQtNetwork.so etc, but the linker is told to look for libQtNetwork_s.so)

I think I'm missing something here.
Also, there is the linker flag

```
-lsip
```

but the only file that looks like a sip shared library is called sip.so (it is in the site-packages directory of the python2.7 virtualenv) instead of libsip.so which is what ld (the linker) is looking for, can I just rename sip.so to libsip.so?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on the [pyqt mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt) (thanks Phil), I didn't find the libraries (qt and sip) because I needed to compile them as static libraries, as described [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/static_builds.html).